# is there a way to know which objects are in "old" area of Heap

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

I have long cycles of GC.
from checks I saw there are too many objects in the tenured (old) area of the Heap.
Is there any utitlity to know which objects are in which area of the heap, or any staticstics about these objects.
I am using Sun/Oracle HotSpot JVM (Java 6).

EDIT: little bit more details about my problem:
I have a big Heap (32GB) and it looks like even when the Heap old area is only 30% full, running GC manually make pauses of 15 sec's. I want to know which objects are the "survivors" that remains in the old area, in order to know which object creation to optimize.

Comment: I have only used [Visualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html), [Visualgc](http://java.sun.com/performance/jvmstat/visualgc.html) and [Jconsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html#gc). I do not recall any of these could list the tenured objects. They'll give you however some stats on the tenured area. So I just recommend this article http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc/index.html and +1

Comment: What's your full set of JVM startup params?

Comment: Cam across this blog post which may be of use to people stumbling upon this question -> https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/how-do-i-find-whats-getting-promoted-to-my-old-generation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not aware of any tool / utility that works with current generation JVMs.

But the flip-side is that I don't see how such a utility would be helpful.

Long GC times typically occur because your heap is too full.  As the heap approaches 100% full, the amount of time spent in the GC tends to grow exponentially.  In the worst case, the heap fills completely and your application gets an `OutOfMemoryError`.  There are two possible solutions:

- If the root cause is that the heap is too small (for the size of problem that your application is trying to solve) then either increase the heap size, or look for a way to reduce the application's working set; i.e. the number / size of objects that it needs to have "live" during the computation.
- If the root cause is a memory leak, then find and fix it.

In both cases, using a memory profiler will help you analyse the problem.  But you don't need to know which objects are in the old generation.  It is not relevant to either the root cause of the problem or the solution to the problem.

---

> I want to know which objects are the "survivors" that remains in the old area, in order to know which object creation to optimize.

This is starting to make a bit more sense.  It sounds like you need to find out which objects are long-lived ... rather than specifically which space they live in.  You could possibly do that by using `jhat` to compare a sequence of heap snapshots.  (There may be a better way ...)

However, I still don't think this approach will help.  The problem is that a full GC needs to traverse all reachable (hard,soft,weak,phantom) objects.  And if you've got a 32Gb heap that is 30% full you've still got a lot of objects to mark/sweep/relocate.  I think the solution is likely to be to use a concurrent collector and tune it so that it can keep up with your application's object allocation rate.

It also sounds like you might be calling `System.gc()` directly from your code.  **Don't do that!**  Calling `System.gc()` will (typically) cause the JVM to do a *full* garbage collection.  That is pretty much *guaranteed* to give you a pause.  It is much better to leave the JVM to decide when to run the collector.

Finally, it is unclear what you mean by "optimizing object creation".  Do you mean reducing the object creation rate?  Or are you thinking of something else to manage the retention of long-lived (cached?) objects?

Comment: Wouldn't it be helpful to know which objects are in the old region when trying to find a Memory Leak? because long lived (referenced objects) should be there and not cleaned even after a full gc right ?

Comment: Ummm ... I don't think so.  If there is sufficient churn of objects, then long lived objects will *probably* be tenured eventually.  But that is GC specific behavior.  Either way, the information is neither necessary or sufficient to determine if an object is leaked.  And (AFAIK) the information is not available anyway.  So your idea is moot ... unless you intend to start hacking on the OpenJDK codebase to implement it ...

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a tool that allows to "explore" the objects in a given generation.

I'm used to Netbeans Profiler. It can't really do what you're asking for but it have a tool that can give you ideas of what is going wrong.

Run the application with Profiler, select `Memory`, then in `Live Results` you have a column `Generations`. **It doesn't told you the generation** of each object but it gives you the number of [`Surviving Generations`](https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/what_do_the_surviving_generations). So if the number is greater than 1 it's probably in the tenured (maybe in survivor space), **if the number always grow you have memory leaks**.

Answer (score 1):

The tool elephant track can profile the object creation and death, [elephantTrack](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/research/redline/elephantTracks/). With this, you may be able to figure out what kind of objects survive longer than expected, and with the method history, it may be possible to get exact objects.

But large heap means very long profile time and very large profile file.

Comment: But ... according to the website it doesn't work for Java 1.7 and (presumably) later versions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any Utility which can tell you about the no of objects in different generations.

1. One way is You can use `jconsole` which comes with jdk. with the help of jconsole you can connect to your application and monitor the all generations , here you might get some figures i am not sure.
2. Other way is you can take a dump using `jmap` and then analyses it using eclipse `MAT` tool.
3. Or you can run your application with below `JVM` arguments and in the log you have the information about GC's

`GC logging is enabled using JVM arguments; below are the arguments I use. (Note: the log file specified as file is reset each time the VM starts.`

`-verbose:gc -Xloggc:file`

I think that may helpful to you.